# GetConsumingEnumerable() blocks after completing of adding

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have async processing of some collection with id's. Simplified code below

```
Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => {
            foreach (long id in ids.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
              //processing code here
            }
        });
```

And another thread that calls CompleteAdding on `ids` after certain condition. But worker thread remains blocked after that. To be precise, worker thread blocks on `in` operator of foreach statement.

How could i resolve that? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'd expect CompleteAdding to do the right thing. Can you post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Can you post the code for adding the ids?

Comment: 2Jon Skeet  - when trying to extract short program that demonstrates a problem I found that that fragment is working as expected. Something other must be causing blocking...

Comment: 2Sign - Just by calling ids.Add(valueToProcess)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var local = ids.GetConsumingEnumerable();
Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => {
            foreach (long id in local)
            {
              //processing code here
            }
        });
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Actually it is same code. But thanx for help